# Pass messages as file through docker-py

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

Is there a way to pass messages as a file through docker and execute it on the docker shell?

For instance, if x  = "print 12345", can I pass the value of x as a python file and copy it into my container. Then use shell to run this python file?

Comment: you can mount a shared folder in docker ... and save the file to that folder ...

Comment: Not quite understand. Can I treat the string as a content and as it does in Dockerfile to

Comment: i dont understand the question ... in your dockerfile you could certainly do `x=(python -c "print 1234")` and x would be an environmental variable equal to 1234